# Где находится и можно ли заменить иконку меню в Linux Mint 11 с рабочим окружением LXDE?

Tags: lxde

Собственно не нравится шестерёнка как кнопка меню, хочу сделать свою. Возникает вопрос, где находится файлы (а их как я думаю два: файл с шестерёнкой в обычном состоянии, и файл с наведенной шестерёнкой) этой шестерёнки и можно ли тупо заменить файлы шестерёнки на файлы с такими же названиями?

Answer (score 1):

/usr/share/icons Можно, меняйте.